# Help with Ubuntu and Windows, separate HDs

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, hard-drive

Need some major help. Running a Dell XPS/Dimension 630i. It came with "SATA 2 RAID 0 With Dual 500GB Hard Drives." I have installed a new, third non-raided drive and installed Ubuntu on it.

So now I have Windows on the original hard drive and Ubuntu Linux on the new HD. When I get to the boot menu where I can select an OS, if I select windows I get an error: "No such drive, no such disk." Also, strangely in the first place, in order to even get to the bootloader menu I have had to disable ALL ports under the RAID config. Unless I do this, I will just get to a never-ending blinking cursor.

I have tried every conceivable CMOS config and nothing else works. Tried setting port 3 (the new HD w/ Ubuntu) to first hard disk boot priority. Tried disabling all other ports and enabling the Ubuntu HD port and vice versa.

I have some pictures of boot up: first one is strange error i get after messing with CMOS to finally get ubuntu install to work.

[image]

Then the boot menu:

[image]

Then error:

[image]

Also, note that I can actually access all files from the raided Windows drive through Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB owned your Windows boot loader. The windows boot loader had to be at the first 4GB of the driver I believe, at the most first 1TB. GRUB over wrote segments of it. You might try repairing the windows installation with your windows disk.

The best order is to install Ubuntu then Windows. Check the Ubuntu forums for more details

Comment: I always do the other way around, first Windows, then something else. Of course, I always partition my HD before installing Windows to make sure I'll have space to my other OS.

Comment: I gave up dual booting. I found I spent more time futzing with it and its issues than was worth. I just got another desktop. Amazingly you don't need and end all video card for bash and gnome.

Comment: Interesting, interesting. Suppose I could back up some pics, etc that I need from the Windows drive and just reformat and Install windows on there.

Comment: @LuxuryMode I would suggest spending some time googling windows boot loader recovery and ubuntu grub. You might save yourself that work, or just learn more about it for the future.

Comment: Or should I format both drives completely and install Ubuntu first and then windows?

Comment: @LuxuryMode I believe the issue to be in the boot sector of your raid 0. I believe you did not flag your new 3rd drive as bootable and GRUB installed the bootloader onto your RAID 0. The people are SuperUser are Sys admins that know this. I am a programmer who has dealt with this a few times before. Trust them not me. :)

Comment: @EnabrenTane: how can I flag my new 3rd drive as bootable and/or change where GRUB installs the bootloader?

Comment: In the Ubuntu installer when setting up the partitiontable there is a "make bootable" flag

Answer (score 1):

Windows Startup Repair from boot CD fixed all!